# how to change settings of composer-rest-server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Earlier I used the command for starting the composer-rest-server and I forgot to make changes in the option they provide like

```
? Specify if you want to enable the explorer test interface: No
```

I clicked on NO 
how can I make changes now as I want to enable the explorer test interface

Comment: Is simply restarting it an option for you ? That would actually be the easiest way

Comment: thanks but after changing comman using -u i was able to do it

Answer (score 0):

simply close server and re-run it. It would ask for option.

composer-rest-server is just server so closing it would not result in loss of data.